# No password prompt in PostgreSQL connection

Tags: postgresql

I wonder why no password prompt in my login try below.
I know if I use `md5` option in `pg_hba.conf` file but I want to check if I can log in without any password with `trust` enabled.

No setting `PGPASSWORD` environment variable.

No `%APPDATA%\postgresql\.pgpass` file / Nowhere

```
psql -U testuser -p 5433 -d postgres
psql (9.5.0)
WARNING: Console code page (1252) differs from Windows code page (949)
         8-bit characters might not work correctly. See psql reference
         page "Notes for Windows users" for details.
Type "help" for help.

postgres=>
postgres=>


pg_hba.conf

# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0            trust
host    all             all             all        trust
```

Comment: what is the question?..

Comment: and on Windows, so it's not using a unix socket (`local` auth)  which is the usual answer

Answer (score 1):

This line says IP4 connections IPv4 localhost need no authentication

```
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
```

This line says all other ip4 connections need no authenticaton

```
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0            trust
```

And this line says all TCP connections (including ipv6) need no authentication

```
host    all             all             all        trust
```

So it's probably the third line allowing connections from ::1 without authentication that causes there to be no password prompt.

Comment: If I use md5, then I can force password authentication. By the way, what if someone edit pg_hba.conf with a value of trust again, then any can log in without a password. Is that right?

Comment: tbat is right.  typically you need to be adminstrator to edit that file